# SSRS and pentaho alternative

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, pentaho

I am using Microsoft Reporting Services to provide users with custom reports. I create them in Business Intelligence studio, deploy them and have a website where users can view those reports.
Now i need i new tool to do almost the same. I need to create reports and users has to be able to view them in PC, Mac, mobile phone, tablet, etc. Microsoft Reporting Services has some problems with Android and iOS, and that is the problem for me. Users cannot scroll the report (if it is longer thant report viewer window), expand does not allways work and etc.
I need a tool, to create same reports and allow to view them anywhere. I was thinking about pentaho, but it is no exactly what i need. Maybe somebody has any solutions?

Comment: Your question is *very* similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804/enterprise-reporting-solutions).

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho's analyzer tool is good on tablets/mobile but unfortunately it is EE only, not community/open source.

If you're happy with enterprise another option is yellowfin?

Alternatively with the community edition of Pentaho you can make use of CTools and there is a very good dashboarding framework with explicit support for mobile devices - may be worth looking at that?

Why exactly is pentaho "not exactly what you need" ?  What are your perceived issues with it?

Comment: Actually i have never tried pentaho. I am just considering it as a good alternative to SSRS, but i am not shure if it fits my needs. I need to create reports exactly the same as with ssrs, because users must have ability to expand/collapse groups, export tables to excel/csv/other format and etc. Also i need to be able to view same reports in pc/mac, phone, tablet.

Comment: The main idea what i need to do, is to allow users view my reports in mobile devices. Problem is - i need reports to be interactive (expand/collapse must have). SSRS does not work properly on Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used pentaho. However, I know any limitations in the web viewer control are based on browser support and interpretation. One workaround to these limitations is to reference the reportexecution2005 interface in your project and call the [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx) method with HTML40 format and designate [HTMLFragment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155395.aspx) in the device context header, this will return the report html content as a byte[]. However, any custom paging/printing/zooming would have to be re-implemented in your web app :(